# How to get the svg PathBounds without using getBBox?

Tags: javascript, svg

In our control we are using getBBox in order to get the path bounds. This affects the performance in Internet explorer alone and makes the rendering slow. Is there any other way to get the path bounds of the svg element without using getBBox. Please   provide your valuable suggestions.

Comment: That's pretty hard to do for all cases e.g. a transformed cubic spline.

Comment: is it possible for svg path node???

Comment: possible, yes. Very hard and too broad to answer here, also yes.

Comment: Please provide any guide link and links to refer so that it will be helpful.

Comment: It would seem very unlikely that any function you write to examine each path segment and calculate the bounding box, is going to be faster written in Javascript than the function provided by the browser.  Perhaps there is another way to speed up whatever you are doing. For example caching the bounding boxes.

Comment: Is there any link available so that the information will be more clearer and am able to proceed further. It is working fine in chrome as well as in mozilla but in IE alone the rendering takes too much time which affects the performance of the entire control. The Internet explorer version i am using is 11.0.9600.17329